# PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null) is very slow

Tags: java

We have a printing in our system.To that need to get print information.
Use **PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null)** method to get printer information.Also use **printService.getSupportedAttributeValues(Media.class, flavor, null)** to get trays.
But this is very slow.
Do we have a way to optimize this call.

```
public class PrintTest
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
    for (int i = 0; i < services.length; i++) {
        PrintService service = services[i];
        System.out.println(service);
        DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PAGEABLE;
        Object o = service.getSupportedAttributeValues(Media.class, flavor, service.getAttributes());
        if (o != null && o.getClass().isArray()) {
            for (Media media : (Media[]) o) {
                if (media instanceof MediaTray) {
                    System.out.println(media + " ID: " + media.getValue() + "\t" + media.getClass().getName());
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

When getting trays it comes with paper types also.But i only need Paper source.

Comment: Is it a local or network printer?

Comment: Network printers.We have 5 printers.

Comment: Well, the problem here is going to be the network overhead involved in communicating with the printers, for example, the first time I ran your code, it took around 7-8 seconds to complete (2 network printers and 4 local printers), subsequent runs take around 2 seconds, so the values are either cached or the connections are (or the printer woke up)

Comment: we have a cache.But first time is the problem.Do we have a way to get only paper sources without types

Comment: I don't think there is really much you can do